# tag form in input not working outside form

Tags: html

This is my form:

```
<div class="form" method="POST" action="application/loaddata.php" id="add-item-form">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="task-label" for="task-name">name:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-size" id="task-name" name="inp-name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="task-label" for="task-email">E-mail:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="task-email" name="inp-email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="task-label" for="task-text">text:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="task-text" rows="5" name="inp-text"></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

My submit button, which outside from form:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success task-button" value="Добавить" name="do_post" form="add-item-form">
```

This is does not work. But if i place input="text" near submit in form, then works.

Comment: there's also no php here

Comment: That sound so weird, and why you use `div` tag instead `form`?

Comment: @Sovary yes, my bad

Comment: *"This is does not work. But if i place input="text" near submit in form, then works."* - This part I don't get.

Comment: @chris85 With HTML5, you can place form-elements outside of the form, and reference the form with the `form` attribute (targets the `<form>` tags with that given id).

Comment: @Qirel Oh, the tricky html5 returns again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have a form! When you write

```
<div class="form" method="POST" action="application/loaddata.php" id="add-item-form">
```

...it's just a `<div>`, and a `<div>` doesn't have a `method` or `action` attribute. You need to use actual `<form>` tags for the form to be valid, and to be able to use `form` attribute as targets for your form in other elements.

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="application/loaddata.php" id="add-item-form">
   <!-- Form-elements goes here -->
</form>
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form